# Install Java 1.4.2 on recent Amazon Linux

Tags: software-installation, rpm, java, binary, aws

I need Java 1.4.2 on a up-to-date Amazon Linux 2015.09 server. I've tried to install `j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-ia64-rpm.bin`. When I execute this file, I get an error message:

```
line 442: ./install.sfx.12314: cannot execute binary file
```

Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way. I downloaded the binary from Oracle, where I see that the most recent Linux (non Solaris) version is Java SE Development Kit 1.4.2_19:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html

- Java SE Development Kit 1.4.2_19  31.69 MB    j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-ia64-rpm.bin
- Java SE Development Kit 1.4.2_19  32.64 MB    j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-ia64.bin

Uname -a shows this:

```
Linux 4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 5 23:44:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried both bin files, and both report the same error.

**How can I install Java 1.4.2 on this machine?**

Comment: "Public support and security updates for Java 1.4 ended in October 2008. Paid security updates for Oracle customers ended in February 2013." Also, it's probably 32-bit, and that looks like a 64-bit machine.

Comment: This bin `j2sdk-1_4_2_19-linux-ia64.bin` looks 64 bit! I don't care about security updates. This will only be used to run one script. The default Java 1.7 install will stay next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ia64` files are for Itanium systems; your Amazon Linux server can't run them. You need to download the `i586` versions.